# Signing with CMS and RSACng in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography, cng

It seems that CNG replaces CSP in .NET Core
As stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.cmssigner.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_Pkcs_CmsSigner__ctor_System_Security_Cryptography_CspParameters_):

> This method is only supported on .NET Framework. Its use on .NET Core
> throws a PlatformNotSupportedException.

But CmsSigner doesn't expose any API to support CNG keys, for example, there is nothing like `CngParameters`, to specify the CNG key to sign with.

When I use `CmsSigner(CspParameters)` in .NET Framework, it creates a dummy certificate used for signing.
I tried this just to see what will happen:

```
var signer = new CmsSigner();
signer.PrivateKey = new RSACng(CngKey.Open("rsaKey"));
signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime());

var signedCms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }), false);
signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
var encodeByteBlock = signedCms.Encode();
```

but it threw this exception at the `ComputeSignature` call:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No signer certificate was
> provided.'

In .NET Framework, I can do this:

```
var cspObj = new CspParameters()
{
    ProviderName = "provider",
    ProviderType = 1,
    KeyNumber = (int)KeyNumber.Signature,
    Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey,
    KeyContainerName = "ContainerName"
};
var signer = new CmsSigner(cspObj)
{
    DigestAlgorithm = new Oid(_signerHashAlgorithmOid)
};

signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime());

var signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);
signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
var encodeByteBlock = signedCms.Encode();
```

Comment: Evidently you need an signer certificate rather than just a private key. A certificate together with it's private key can be provided with an `X509Certificate2` object.

Comment: I edited the question to illustrate why I need this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the .NET Core implementation you need to provide a certificate with a bound private key.  If the certificate isn't important for your purposes, you can create a dummy certificate of your own.  This sample uses RSA-SHA256 whereas the CspParameters version in .NET Framework uses RSA-SHA1, but otherwise it's essentially the same.

```
using (CngKey cngKey = CngKey.Open(...))
using (RSA rsa = new RSACng(cngKey))
{
    CertificateRequest req = new CertificateRequest(
        "CN=CMS Signer Dummy Certificate",
        rsa,
        HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
        RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

    DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

   using (X509Certificate2 cert = req.CreateSelfSigned(now, now.AddYears(1)))
   {
       CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(cert);
       ...
   }
}
```